# No titlebar and no scrollbars in a gtk3 app in Plasma desktop

Tags: ubuntu, theme, gtk3, tilix

I'm using a GTK3 app called *Tilix*. It's a terminal app.

I have 2 computers with KDE Neon based on **Ubuntu 16.04 LTS**.

In one of them, *Tilix* works ok. In the other one, no title bars and no scrollbars are painted. It is like they were transparent.

Investigating a little, I've seen it uses the gtk3 theme called *Breeze*. No theme customization.

I've tried to compare both computers, and to reinstall *Tilix*. How can I solve this? I think there must be some theme misconfiguration.

Comment: *if* this is a variation of [a previous question](https://superuser.com/questions/1303975/firefox-scrollbar-appearance), please consider deleting one of them. (Ref: [cross-posting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic))

Comment: The other question is for CentOS, and it's not the same having different scrollbar appearance, that no titlebar and no usability at all.